# Java User Interface Customization

Tags: java, user-interface, customization

Is there a way to make my user interface look good? Like not something that looks like it was made in the 90's appearance wise.... I have to standard, JFrame, JPanel, JButton, JLabel, JTextField, JTextArea, etc.

Basically are there any tools out there to make my user interface look like its from the 21st century?

Thanks for any input

Comment: Have you looked at JavaFX?

Comment: Either JavaFX or use a custom Look-and-Feel that fits your needs.

Comment: I have not, is that just basically another form of javax.swing?

Comment: @javaGeek It looks much better than Swing IMO: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/get_start_apps.htm#JFXST804

Comment: @assylias are you able to use this not using the netbeans environment?

Comment: Sure. There is also sort of a [GUI builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/jsbpub-use_java_ides.htm) that works with every IDE.